# Mismatch between LX standard font and typewriter font size

Tags: beamer, fontsize, font-encodings

I'm using lxfonts in a beamer presentation, and I noticed that whenever I use \texttt{foo}, the typewriter font is much smaller than the regular font. I also noticed that the problem goes away if I use ${\tt foo}$ instead (but that's not really a solution) or if I don't use fontenc (but then the German umlauts look ugly). Is there a better solution?

Also, if I manage to get the height of the letters right (as described above), the lines of the typewriter letters' lines are thicker than the regular text, so the letters look like boldface. It would be nice if I could fix this too, but if that's not possible, I could live with that.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lxfonts}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}



\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Text \texttt{Text}}

text {\tt text} \texttt{text} 

$text$ ${\tt text}$ $\texttt{text}$ 


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scale the fonts, but as you already remarked that makes them also bolder.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lxfonts}

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{llcmtt}{\hyphenchar\font-1}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{llcmtt}{m}{n}{<-> s*[1.22]ec-lmtt10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{llcmtt}{m}{it}{<-> s*[1.22]ec-lmtti10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{llcmtt}{m}{sl}{<-> ssub* llcmtt/m/it}{}
 \DeclareFontShape{T1}{llcmtt}{bx}{n}{<-> ssub* llcmtt/m/n}{}
 \DeclareFontShape{T1}{llcmtt}{bx}{it}{<-> ssub* llcmtt/m/it}{}
 \DeclareFontShape{T1}{llcmtt}{bx}{sl}{<-> ssub* llcmtt/m/it}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Text \texttt{Text}}

text {\tt text} \texttt{text}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'll go with this solution.